# What is the best way to create a sitemap.xml?

Tags: php, mysql, sitemap

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to create a sitemap using PHP & MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4018919/how-to-create-a-sitemap-using-php-mysql)

So I'm kinda stuck here. I have a website with a pretty big database, that constantly changes. Now I want to help the search engines by supplying a sitemap.xml file. Normally I would use a webservice that would do this, but thats not really possible in this case.

To be honest. **I have no clue where to start**. How would I go about doing this? Sorry if this is a too basic question, but Google couldn't help me.

Edit: Some more info. DB is currently 1k pages. Want to go up to like 10k. I use Mysql to echo this from my database, and then htaccess to rewrite the URLs.
(PHP's get ID, etc)

Comment: Can't you set a cronjob to run once a day, and compile the list to an xml file?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install a crawler of doing it like a webservice. The easier way is to write a php script and generate sitemap XML file by yourself.

Write a query to get the links from your database and then iterate over it to create a sitemap.

See this post for example php script [How to create a sitemap using PHP & MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4018919/how-to-create-a-sitemap-using-php-mysql)